If I can't use subtraction to test whether addition has overflowed, then how can you use division to test whether multiplication has overflowed?
int sum = x+y;
sum-x == y;

If sum overflows, then sum-x will not be equal to y and overflow is detected.  But if sum has not overflowed, then sum-x==y is equal to y. Then why is this logic not used?
I understand the logic below, and it works fine, but why can't we use the above logic? If possible, give some examples where the above logic fails?
if ( x>0&&y>0&&sum<0 ) {
    printf( "Postive overflow" )
}
if ( x<0&&y<0&&sum>0 ) {
    printf("Negative overflow")
} 


If sum has overflowed, the result is undefined behaviour — there is no way to reason about what happened.  C23 provides the <stdckdint.h> header and type-generic macros ckd_add(), ckd_sub(), ckd_mul() (but not ckd_div()).  The checking you provide with if (x > 0 && y > 0 && sum < 0) etc is not guaranteed to work because the behaviour on the overflow of signed integers is undefined.  It may work in your test environment — it may not work everywhere.

Your question title mentions multiplication and division, but does not demonstrate what you mean by "how can you use division to test whether multiplication has overflowed".  Note that after overflow has occurred (whether by addition, subtraction, multiplication or division), all bets are off.  You need to test before invoking an operator where the result might overflow.  (Division only overflows in numerator / denominator for type int if numerator == INT_MIN && denominator == -1.

See for instance https://www.gnu.org/software/c-intro-and-ref/manual/html_node/Signed-Overflow.html


Then why is this logic not used?

Because it may end up in undefined behavior or implementation defined behavior.
From C11#6.5p5

If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

which means signed integer overflow is UB.
(Note that it is not applicable to unsigned integer type - #6.2.5p9.)
and from C11#6.3.1.3p3

3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Here,
int sum = x+y;

You haven't mentioned the type of x and y.
If x and y both are of type int and x+y overflow i.e. the result of addition is not in range of representable values for int type then it's UB. Otherwise, if either of x or y is unsigned or any type of greater rank than int type and result of their addition cannot be represented in an int type the behavior will be implementation defined.
I am assuming that both x and y are of type int.
You can use subtraction to test whether addition of x and y will result in UB or not:
for y > 0
x + y > INT_MAX   ---> Overflow

for y < 0
x + y < INT_MIN   ---> Underflow

You can do:
bool is_add_ub (int x, int y) {
    return (y > 0 && x > (INT_MAX - y)) || (y < 0 && x < (INT_MIN - y));
}

Similarly, you can use division to test whether multiplication of int x and y will result in UB or not:
x * y > INT_MAX   ---> Overflow
x * y < INT_MIN   ---> Underflow

Multiplication of x and y is UB, if any of below equations result in true -
x > 0 and y > 0 and x > INT_MAX / y
x < 0 and y < 0 and y < INT_MAX / x  
x > 0 and y < 0 and y < INT_MIN / x
x < 0 and y > 0 and x < INT_MIN / y  



how can you use division to test whether multiplication has overflowed?

Test if operation would fail and then if so, avoid it as not to cause undefined behavior (UB).
Sample code: int is_undefined_mult1(int a, int b)
Example: For addition
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Return true when addition will overflow.
bool add(int *sum, int a, int b) {
 if (a >= 0) {
   if (b > INT_MAX - a) {
     return true;
   }
 } else {
   if (b < INT_MIN - a) {
     return true;
   }
 }
 *sum = a + b;
 return false;
}

Or use the new C23 approach for +, -, *:

If these macros return false, the value assigned to *result correctly represents the mathematical result of the operation. Otherwise, these macros return true. In this case, the value assigned to *result is the mathematical result of the operation wrapped around to the width of *result.

if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 202311
// Declared in <stdckdint.h>
bool ckd_add(type1 *result, type2 a, type3 b);
#endif



If sum overflows, then sum-x will not be equal to y and overflow is detected.

This is incorrect. When x+y overflows, sum may be set to the result x + y wrapped modulo 2N, where N is the number of bits in the int type. When sum-x may also wrap modulo 2N, and == will evaluate as true, and overflow will not be detected.
Other behaviors are possible too. Note that in int sum = x+y;, it is the operation x+y that overflows; it is not sum that overflows. The C standard does not define the behavior when overflow occurs. It does not guarantee you get any result in sum at all; the entire behavior of the program is not defined.
You might get a result that wraps, as described above. Alternately, the optimizer in the compiler might observe that sum-x == y is always true for all cases that are defined by the C standard, and therefore it can optimize this expression to 1, so it would always evaluate as true, even if the overflow in x+y caused some other value to be produced in sum. Or this code might interact with its surrounding environment in some way that caused the program to behave as if some very different value were produced in sum. Once overflow is present, any behavior the compiler produces for this code conforms to the C standard.

… how can you use division to test whether multiplication has overflowed?

You cannot use division as a reliable test of whether multiplication overflows. It is not clear why you think you could. As with addition, the behavior when overflow occurs is not defined by the C standard.

I am talking about this problem.That's why I asked if division can be used to detect multiplication overflow,then why subtraction can't be used to detect additional overflow.Now I know why subtraction can't be used.[https://i.sstatic.net/M6yBFrHp.png]

This is a example where the logic above fails :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = 0x7ffffff0;
    int y = 0x0300;
    int sum = x + y;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    printf("sum - x = %d\n", sum - x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Result:
x = 2147483632
y = 768
sum = -2147482896
sum - x = 768

Why ? Without entering in math theories, just simply thinks that if x + y makes overflow, sum - x makes "underflow", which cancels the overflow.

This is a common result — but it is not guaranteed.  Once signed integer overflow occurs, all bets are off; the result of the overflow is undefined behaviour.

Thanks I got it. sum-x will always be equal to y,irrespective of sum has overflown or not. if sum has overflown then the value of sum wraps around,and  wrapped value is stored in sum variable. Then again sum-x is performed ,it again overflows and actual value of y is given. for example;
short x= -32760  short y=-9  short sum=-32769 (overflow,assume sum isnot converted to int) then sum=32767(0111111111111111) sum-x=65527(over flow) then sum-x=-9(1111111111110111).

You can't do the test after the overflow has occurred, but you can test if the operation will overflow:
if ( x > INT_MAX / y )
  // x * y will overflow
else
  z = x * y;

If it's true that x * y > z, then it's true that x > z / y.
